# How can I count candy bars that are greater than or equal to the input parameter?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have to make a method that return all the candy bars that weigh greater than or equal to the input parameter in this case greater than 1.75. I tried making my own method but it doesnt seem to work.. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. I am going to post both methods in the bottom.. I have tried using the forloop but i dont know how to add the numbers together.

MAIN:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Lab16
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayList<CandyBar> bars = new ArrayList<CandyBar>();
    addCandyBarsToList(bars);

    /**
     * Use the methods you wrote below to answer all of
     * the following questions.
     */

    /**
     * Part A:
     */

    /**
     * Is Twix in the list?
     * If so, print all information about it.
     * If not, print a message to the user.
     */

    int location = findCandyBar(bars, "Twix");
    if(location == -1){
        System.out.println("The Candy bar is not in the list");
    } else{
        bars.get(location).printInfo();
    }

    /**
     * Is Mounds in the list?
     * If so, print all information about it.
     * If not, print a message to the user.
     */
    System.out.println();
    int index = findCandyBar(bars, "Mounds");
    if(index == 1){
        System.out.println("The Candy bar is not in the list");
    } else{
        bars.get(index).printInfo();
    }
    /**
     * Part B:
     */

    /**
     * Print all the names of candy bars with yellow wrappers.
     */

    findByColor(bars, CandyBar.Color.YELLOW);


    /**
     * Part C:
     */

    /**
     * Count how many candy bars are 1.75 oz or more.
     */
    double weight = countByWeight(bars, 1.75);
    if(weight >= 1.75){
        System.out.println(weight);
    }else{
        System.out.println("They are no candy bars with that much weight");
    }



    /**
     * Part D:
     */

    /**
     * Is there a candy bar that is 1.86 oz?
     * If so, print the information.
     * If not, print a message to the user.
     * Write a binary search method to get the answer.
     */


}

/**
 * This method searches a list to find a candy bar by name.
 *
 * @param   list    the list to search
 * @param   n       a name to find
 * @return          the index of the candy bar 
 */
public static int findCandyBar(ArrayList<CandyBar> list, String n)
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).getName() == n){
            return i;
        }
}
return 1;
}
/**
 * This method prints the names of the candy bars that have a certain
 * wrapper color.
 *
 * @param   list    the list to search
 * @param   c       the color wrapper to find 
 */
public static void findByColor(ArrayList<CandyBar> list, CandyBar.Color c)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).getWrapperColor() == CandyBar.Color.YELLOW){
       System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }  else{
      System.out.println("There is no such candy bar with that color");
}
}
```

}

```
/**
 * This method counts the number of candy bars that weigh greater than
 * or equal to the weight input parameter.
 *
 * @param   list    the list to search
 * @param   w       the weight to compare to
 * @return          the count of candy bars 
 */
public static int countByWeight(ArrayList<CandyBar> list, double weight)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).getWeight() >= 1.70){
            return 
     }
 }
 return 1;
}
/**
 * This method searches a list using binary search.
 *
 * @param   list    the list to search
 * @param   first   the first index
 * @param   last    the last index
 * @param   w       the value to search for
 * @return          the index of the candy bar 
 */
public static int binaryFind(ArrayList<CandyBar> list, int first, int last, double w)
{
    return -1;
}

/**
 * This method adds candy bars to a list.
 *
 * @param   list    the list to add to
 */
public static void addCandyBarsToList(ArrayList<CandyBar> list)
{
    CandyBar kitkat = new CandyBar("KitKat", CandyBar.Color.RED, 1.5);
    list.add(kitkat);
    CandyBar grand = new CandyBar("One-hundred Grand", CandyBar.Color.RED, 1.5);
    list.add(grand);
    CandyBar crunch = new CandyBar("Crunch", CandyBar.Color.BLUE, 1.55);
    list.add(crunch);
    CandyBar hershey = new CandyBar("Hershey", CandyBar.Color.BROWN, 1.55);
    list.add(hershey);
    CandyBar krackel = new CandyBar("Krackel", CandyBar.Color.RED, 1.55);
    list.add(krackel);
    CandyBar caramello = new CandyBar("Caramello", CandyBar.Color.PURPLE, 1.6);
    list.add(caramello);
    CandyBar what = new CandyBar("Whatchamacallit", CandyBar.Color.YELLOW, 1.6);
    list.add(what);
    CandyBar almond = new CandyBar("Almond Joy", CandyBar.Color.BLUE, 1.61);
    list.add(almond);
    CandyBar goodbar = new CandyBar("Mr. Goodbar", CandyBar.Color.YELLOW, 1.75);
    list.add(goodbar);
    CandyBar twix = new CandyBar("Twix", CandyBar.Color.GOLD, 1.79);
    list.add(twix);
    CandyBar henry = new CandyBar("Oh Henry", CandyBar.Color.YELLOW, 1.8);
    list.add(henry);
    CandyBar milkyWay = new CandyBar("Milky Way", CandyBar.Color.GREEN, 1.84);
    list.add(milkyWay);
    CandyBar payDay = new CandyBar("PayDay", CandyBar.Color.ORANGE, 1.85);
    list.add(payDay);
    CandyBar snickers = new CandyBar("Snickers", CandyBar.Color.BLUE, 1.86);
    list.add(snickers);
    CandyBar butterfinger = new CandyBar("Butterfinger", CandyBar.Color.YELLOW, 1.9);
    list.add(butterfinger);
    CandyBar musketeers = new CandyBar("Three Musketeers", CandyBar.Color.SILVER, 1.92);
    list.add(musketeers);
    CandyBar reeses = new CandyBar("Reese's FastBreak", CandyBar.Color.ORANGE, 2);
    list.add(reeses);
    CandyBar babyRuth = new CandyBar("Baby Ruth", CandyBar.Color.SILVER, 2.1);
    list.add(babyRuth);
}
```

}

Method:

```
public class CandyBar
     {
       public enum Color { BLUE, BROWN, GOLD, GREEN, ORANGE, PURPLE, RED, SILVER, WHITE, YELLOW }

// instance variables
private String name;
private double weight;
private Color wrapper;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class CandyBar
 */
public CandyBar(String n, Color c, double w)
{
    this.name = n;
    this.weight = w;
    this.wrapper = c;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public double getWeight()
{
    return this.weight;
}

public Color getWrapperColor()
{
    return this.wrapper;
}

public void printInfo()
{
    System.out.println(this.name);
    System.out.printf("%.1f oz with a ", this.weight);
    System.out.println(this.wrapper + " wrapper");
}
```

}

Comment: Problem here: `if(list.get(i).getName() == n){`

Comment: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Also, your `countByWeight(...)` does no counting but returns immediately if any candy bar is found that matches or exceeds the desired weight. Does this make logical sense to you? You thus have a problem with basic logic, not with coding syntax.

Comment: I am still pretty new at this but i see what you mean. Well how do I make the method return the number of candy bars greater than 1.75?

Comment: You need a counter variable to increment each time you see a bar with a greater weight. Then once you've finished the loop, return the counter variable.

Comment: When calling `findCandyBar()`, the first time you expect `-1` to mean not found, but the second time you expect `1` to mean not found. Your implementation of the method currently returns `1`, but should return `-1` otherwise how do you tell the difference between not found and the bar at index 1?

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
            if(list.get(i).getWeight() >= 1.70){
                weight ++;
                return weight;
         }
     }                                      like this??

Comment: No, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to count bars heavier or equal to the specified weight:

```
public static int countByWeight(ArrayList<CandyBar> list, double weight)
{
    int countOfBarsHeavierOrEqual = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).getWeight() >= weight){
            countOfBarsHeavierOrEqual++; 
        }
    }
    return countOfBarsHeavierOrEqual;
}
```

Also, your `findCandyBar()` implementation should be:

```
public static int findCandyBar(ArrayList<CandyBar> list, String n)
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if(list.get(i).getName().equals(n)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Then fix this execution:

```
int index = findCandyBar(bars, "Mounds");
if(index == -1){    // <-- check for -1 to see if not found
```

**EDIT**: One way to make the 'not found' situation obvious is to set a constant at the top of your class:

```
private static final int NOT_FOUND = -1;
```

Then wherever you want to return something was not found, or test for it:

```
return NOT_FOUND;
```

... or ...

```
if(index == NOT_FOUND){
```

Comment: That makes alot of sense now. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static int countByWeight(ArrayList<CandyBar> list, double weight) {
    return (int)list.stream().map(CandyBar::getWeight).filter(w -> w >= weight).count();
}
```

Note that your code ignored the `weight` parameter and instead hard-coded `1.70` as the threshold.

Comment: Correct - if the OP is using Java8+.

Comment: @Jason java 8??? Quoting [the doc](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html): *Java SE 8 has gone through the End of Public Updates process*

Comment: Older versions than Java8 are still in use around the world. Just because Java8 has hit end-of-public-updates doesn't mean that it or its predecessors don't work any more or aren't used any more.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I'm a Streams proponent. Your solution is the way I would generally do it. I just think people learning Java should also learn the 'old' way of doing things so they understand how things work.